# Why $\le$ sign rather than $<$ sign only? If $x_1<x_2 \implies f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$ then the function is increasing.

Tags: functions

If $x_1<x_2 \implies f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$ then the function is increasing. If $x_1<x_2 \implies f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ then the function is strictly increasing.
By this definition it seems that if for any $x_1<x_2 \space \space \space f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then the function is still increasing but output values are constant. Second definition makes sense, but I don't see why would we define a function to be increasing with $\le$ sign rather than only with $< \space$?

Comment: A lot of theorems only require a function to be increasing and not strictly increasing. This definition is then useful for such theorems.

Comment: But my question is how is the function increasing if the function is constant i.e. $f(x_1)= f(x_2)$ for some $x_1<x_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you are seeking is that the function is nondecreasing. It doesn't have to be increasing, but it can't be decreasing. That's what the $\le$ sign is for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This seems to be a convention thing. I'll take that for now.

Answer (score 2):

It dependents upon the text you are studying. Sometimes non decreasing and increasing are same. Usually the definition you have mentioned is for non decreasing is also valid for increasing and $x_1<x_2\Rightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ is used for stricaly increasing.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @ToTheSpace2 your welcome.